How do i discover the memory consumption of objects in code
I want evaluate object sizes in memory via Diagnostics, but I´m a litte confused, how can the size of all objects in memeory be higher than the total memrory size ?
The GC.GetTotalMemory() gives me a other value (lower) then when I loop through all objects on the heap and summarize them:
TotalSize: 22236, ObjectSize: 452999
And when i look in taskmanager the Memory consumption has another differnent value (11,4 MB)?
So what is the real memory consumption? My target is to track our objects and the consumption.
What I´m doing wrong?
    private static void EvaluateMemoryConsumption()
    {
        GC.Collect(); 
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers(); 
        GC.Collect();
    
        long totalMemory = GC.GetTotalMemory(forceFullCollection: false);
        long totalObjSize = 0;
    
        using (var dataTarget = DataTarget.AttachToProcess(Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id, suspend: false))
        {
            using (var runtime = dataTarget.ClrVersions[0].CreateRuntime())
            {
                foreach (var segment in runtime.Heap.Segments)
                {
                    foreach (var obj in segment.EnumerateObjects())
                    {
                       totalObjSize += (long)obj.Size;                          
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    
        Console.WriteLine($"TotalSize: {totalMemory}, ObjectSize: {totalObjSize}");   
        
        // TotalSize: 22236, ObjectSize: 452999
    }


Consider using a proper memory profiler such as dotMemory or ANTS

We have dotMemeory and Telerik JustTrace, but I need to do it in code and want to interpret the numbers.
How can GC.GetTotalMemeory be lower tahn the size of all object in the heap?

I'm guessing you are using ClrMD? I would be very careful about interpreting its data unless you have an in depth understanding of the memory system. There is a lot of details that I sure don't have a full understanding of. I would check if a third party memory profiler agrees with GetTotalMemory, and if so, ignore your totalObjectSize as erroneous.
